# Is the change in momentum of each object in a collision the same?

Tags: momentum

I have this question concerned with collisions

[image]

In the solutions, they work out the change in momentum of the blue car, which comes to 0.048. I also calculated the change in momentum of the red car 0.05 × (1.5 – 0.54) = 0.048.

Why are these values the same? I have also seen another question in my textbook where the two cars stick together, and the change in momentum of both cars is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F \Delta t=m \Delta v$, the momentum change for each car must be equal and opposite to the momentum change of the other car since by Newton's third law the force on each car in the collision is equal and opposite to force on the other car.  Also the duration of the force is the same for each object.

The force in the above equation is the average force over the time of the collision.